# Surface potential resulting from the charge transfer between insulator and conductor

Tags: electrostatics, potential

Common non-contact electrostatic voltmeters are used to measure the surface potential. Imagine we place a charged insulator on top of the conducting plate (insulated from the surrounding) and measure the resulting potential from the bottom of the plate. 
How is the measured potential related to the charge transferred from the insulator?

To my understanding, the charge will be transferred from the insulator to conductor only at their interface. Therefore, the potential detected by the voltmeter at conductor surface should be only due to this portion of charge transferred. Is that correct? 
Does the conductivity affect the surface potential detected? If yes, what is the relationship?

I do not have much experience in electrostatic events, I am a chemist trying to understand the above situation.